# Quicksearch using jquery quicksearch plugin in asp.net table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to implement jquery quicksearch plugin in my asp.net application.
the below code is working in ASP.NET GridView but not in a ASP.NET table. Please Help

I have a ASP.NET table and I want to filter/search the table row on keydown/textchange event on a textbox in realtime. Whenever I type something in the textbox, if the particular text is present in the table, only that particular row should be visible.

Please help...
My project going to go live in 9 days.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#Table1 tbody tr');
             })
    </script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>

<form runat="server">
  <div>
    <input id=id_search type=text placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="table table-responsive">
       <asp:TableHeaderRow>
         
          <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Block"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Flat"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
          <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Name"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
         
       </asp:TableHeaderRow>
       
             <asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="B-Wing"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="101"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="ABC"></asp:TableCell>
             </asp:TableRow>
       
             <asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="A-wing"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="102"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="DEF"></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
       
    </asp:Table>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tbody is not getting generated...Also check below jquery reference

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#Table1 tr');
    });

    </script>
```

**EDIT : Full source code of the page which works at my machine
Ensure that Scripts are present in their place.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ControlTest.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="ControlTest" Namespace="ControlTest" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<%--<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

<script src="jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


  <div>
    <input id=id_search type=text placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  CssClass="table table-responsive">
       <asp:TableHeaderRow>

          <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Block"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
          <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Flat"></asp:TableHeaderCell>
          <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Name"></asp:TableHeaderCell>

       </asp:TableHeaderRow>

             <asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="B-Wing"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="101"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="ABC"></asp:TableCell>
             </asp:TableRow>

             <asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="A-wing"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="102"></asp:TableCell>
                 <asp:TableCell Text="DEF"></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>

    </asp:Table>
  </div>


<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#Table1 tr');
        $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#Table1 tr');
    });
            //
    </script>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```